# CSGO 30fps on rx 560 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, steam, amdgpu-pro

I installed amdgpu-pro drivers and when playing any game I have low FPS compared to what I have previously experienced. For example, in CS:GO I am getting around 30-60 FPS and sometimes as low as 5.

I was getting around 130 fps but that was probably using the integrated GPU on my processor. What can I do to ensure that I'm using the correct driver for my video card and that it's configured correctly?

Comment: What is your question? This isn't a bug reporting site, so if you're just reporting a bug about AMDGPU Pro, you need to report that to AMD.

Comment: my question is how to fix it (if there is a solution ) I tried changing from auto to high and GPU clock is 1216 MHz but on ubuntu 17.10 I had ~130 fps but AMD drivers aren't working o ubuntu 17.10 so I downgraded to 16.04

Comment: i dont game but i know that games have lower fps on linux than windows. Thats all i know. My advice if you're a gamer install windows 10 or dualboot

Comment: I think this is a good question but needs to be improved. I submitted an edit suggestion, please take a look when it's approved and be sure to make any adjustments if I assumed anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed id by uninstalling amdgpu-pro drivers and instead of installing amdgpu-pro drivers i installed amdgpu drivers and it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the gpupro drives are only supported on Ubuntu 16.04, according to the release notes:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx

As of last month 17.10 was definitely not supported, and I am unable to find anything to suggest that this has changed in the meantime:

https://community.amd.com/thread/221534

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much in the way of a workaround at this time, other than using Ubuntu 16.04, integrated graphics, or switching to a graphics card that has supported drivers.